# python stoped iterator while trying to create lists of sequences and inserting it in excel using panda

Tags: python, loops, pycharm, sequence, python-itertools

I am trying to create a list of 6 numbers lists from 1 to 49 throw looping from 1 to 49 and creating all possible sets of 1 to 49 .
the issue is that code stops at number 15 and in Pycharm nothing is being printed (excel file is being written but stops at 38759 record)

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
all=[]

for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        alist=list(subset)
        if len(subset)==6:
            all.append(alist)

all_tuple=tuple(all)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_tuple,columns=['z1','z2','z3','z4','z5','z6'])
print(df)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Are you wanting to find all the possible combinations of 6 numbers sampled from the list `[1, 2, 3, ..., 49]` without replacement?

Comment: yes .Find the number of terms in the set c(n,k) =>c(49,6) which equal to C(49,6)=13983816 sets

Comment: Okay. Well are you sure that an Excel file can have 13.9 million rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find the possible combinations of 6 numbers sampled from the list `[1, 2, 3, ..., 49]` without replacement.

But your code calculates the combinations of all lengths and then only saves those of length 6.

To get a clue as to why your code does not terminate quickly, consider the number of combinations of 6 numbers:

```
>>> print(len(list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 50), 6))))
13983816
```

So, if there are 14 million possible combinations of 6 numbers, imagine how many combinations there are of 7, 8, 9, ...

Here is some code to calculate only the 14 million combinations of length 6:

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 50), 6))
```

Or, if you really want to build the dataframe:

```
# Warning, this takes about 25 seconds
combs = itertools.combinations(range(1, 50), 6)
df = pd.DataFrame(combs, columns=['z1','z2','z3','z4','z5','z6'])
```

Bear in mind that this will take up quite a bit of memory.  I'm not sure if Excel can handle 14 million rows so I didn't risk it.

Also, don't use reserved keywords for variable names. `all` is a built in Python function.

Comment: Why vaguely "imagine"... overall it's simply 2^49 combinations. And they're not using any [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) as variable names. Otherwise their code wouldn't even execute at all (except for soft keywords, but they're not using any of those, either).

Comment: thanks a lot . you are right and excel can record just 1,048,576  rows .

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem.